How To Fix Naming Conflicts Causing Broken Clothing/Shader UI?
Novice Blender user here 
I downloaded two models from a popular character modeler online. The models use the Character-UI add-on by nextr3d to manage clothing/shader options. They are great models, however, I have noticed an issue with the scripts from the add-on whenever I try to use more than one model at a time.
The file names for the clothes/shaders are the same for both models, so when I append the model with another model, the add-on script finds it difficult to find the correct clothing and shaders so I can edit their appearance. What ends up happening is I can only edit clothes/shaders for one model (whichever one was appended first) versus editing them individually.
I reached out to the creator about this. They explained that I have to go into the original file, rename the clothing files so they do not match, and then update the script in the add-on so it remembers the new names. This is beyond my Blender knowledge. It also does not explain how to fix the shaders, only the clothes. Do I have to rename the shaders as well?
I would GREATLY appreciate any help showing me how to fix the clothes/shaders!
Links:
Model found here
Character-UI add-on
